# Asignar el valor de una publicación a los inputs y combo para luego editar los valores REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parametros

deseo recuperar la información de una publicación en particular y asignar a los campos correspondientes los valores de la misma. El proceso de recuperar el modelo esta hecho pero no puedo hacer que se carguen los campos con dicha info.

Este seria mi componente principal (TAB), de aqui paso la info a los hijos

```
export default function VehiclePublicationPage() {
  const [, setLocation] = useLocation();
  const [key, setKey] = useState("principal");
  const [match, params] = useRoute("/publication/:id");

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    personId: getLocalStorage("userId"),
    title: "",
    condition: "",
    vehicleCategoryId: "",
    vehicleMakeId: "",
    vehicleModelId: "",
    vehiculoVersionId: "",
    vehicleMake: "",
    vehicleModel: "",
    vehicleVersion: "",
    vehicleCustomMake: "",
    vehicleCustomModel: "",
    vehicleCustomVersion: "",
    km: "",
    year: "",
    uniqueOwner: "",
    transmision: "",
    engine: "",
    fuelType: "",
    doors: "",
    cityId: "",
    price: "",
    currencyType: "",
    files: [],
  });
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState([]);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [makes, setMakes] = useState([]);
  const [models, setModels] = useState([]);
  const [versions, setVersions] = useState([]);

  const [customMake, setCustomMake] = useState(null);
  const [customModel, setCustomModel] = useState(null);
  const [customVersion, setCustomVersion] = useState(null);
  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [editResponse, setEditResponse] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getPublicationEdit() {
      const editCar = await getPublicationId(params.id);
      if (editCar.status === 200) {
        setEditResponse(editCar.data.response);
        console.log("hola" + editResponse);
      }
    }
    getPublicationEdit();
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function handleGetCategories() {
      const result = await getCategories();
      setCategories(result.data);
      console.log(result.data);
    }
    handleGetCategories();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function handleLoading() {
      if (loading) {

        swal({
          title: "Cargando...",
          buttons: false,
        });
      }
    }
    handleLoading();
  }, [loading]);

  const onChangeOptionCategory = async (event) => {
    const val = event.target.value;
    const result = await getMakesByCategoryId({
      vehicleCategoryId: val,
    });
    setMakes(result.data.response);
    onChangeInput(event);
  };

  const onChangeOptionMake = async (event) => {
    const val = event.target.value;
    if (val === "other") {
      setCustomMake("");
    } else {
      const vehicleCategoryId = document.getElementById(
        "vehicleCategorySelect"
      ).value;
      setCustomMake(null);
      const result = await getModelsByMakeIdAndCategoryId({
        vehicleMakeId: val,
        vehicleCategoryId,
      });
      setModels(result.data);
    }
    const selectedElement =
      event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text;
    setFormData((formData) => {
      return { ...formData, vehicleMake: selectedElement };
    });
    onChangeInput(event);
  };

  const onChangeOptionModel = async (event) => {
    const val = event.target.value;
    if (val === "other") {
      setCustomModel("");
    } else {
      setCustomModel(null);
      const result = await getVersionsByModelId({
        vehicleModelId: event.target.value,
      });
      setVersions(result.data);
    }
    const selectedElement =
      event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text;
    setFormData((formData) => {
      return { ...formData, vehicleModel: selectedElement };
    });
    onChangeInput(event);
  };

  const onChangeOptionVersion = (event) => {
    const val = event.target.value;
    if (val === "other") {
      setCustomVersion("");
    } else {
      setCustomVersion(null);
      onChangeInput(event);
    }
    const selectedElement =
      event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text;
    setFormData((formData) => {
      return { ...formData, vehicleVersion: selectedElement };
    });
    onChangeInput(event);
  };

  const checkboxValue = (event) => {
    return event.target.checked;
  };

  const onChangeInput = (event) => {
    let val;
    if (event.target.type === "checkbox") {
      val = checkboxValue(event);
    } else {
      val = event.target.value;
    }
    setFormData((formData) => {
      return { ...formData, [event.target.name]: val };
    });
  };

  const onChangeTab = (keyTab) => {
    const formElement = document.getElementById("publicationForm");
    if (!formElement.checkValidity()) {
      formElement.reportValidity();
    } else {
      setKey(keyTab);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await postPublication(formData);

                    if (response.error) {
                        swal({
                          title: "Oops",
                          icon: "error",
                          text: response.error.message,
                        });
                    } else {
                        setLoading(true);
                        await submitImages(response.data.id);
                        setLoading(false);
                          swal({
                            title: "¡Vehículo publicado exitosamente!",
                            icon: "success",
                            button: "Ir a la publicación",
                            allowOutsideClick: false,
                          }).then(() => {
                            setLocation(`/vehicle/detail/${response.data.slugUrl}`);
                          });
                    }
  };

  const hasVehicleOtherSelected = () => {
    return (
      formData["vehicleMakeId"] === "other" ||
      formData["vehicleModelId"] === "other" ||
      formData["vehicleVersionId"] === "other"
    );
  };

  const deleteFile = (event) => {
    const fileName = event.currentTarget.value;
    const filteredFileList = [...selectedFile].filter(
      (file) => file.name !== fileName
    );
    setSelectedFile(filteredFileList);
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    let files = event.target.files;
    const filesFromStatusCount = selectedFile.length;

    const createImgPreviewUrl = (files) => {
      for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
        files[index].imagePreviewUrl = URL.createObjectURL(files[index]);
      }
    };

    if (
      maxSelectFile(event, filesFromStatusCount) &&
      checkMimeType(event) &&
      maxFileSize(event)
    ) {
      createImgPreviewUrl(files);
      if (selectedFile.length === 0) {
        setSelectedFile(files);
      } else {
        setSelectedFile([...selectedFile, ...files]);
      }
    } else {
      swal({
        title: "Oops, verifica las imágenes",
        icon: "error",
        text: "Verifica que sean de un tipo válido (png, jpeg o jpg), tamaño máximo por imágen (2mb) y cantidad máxima de imágenes 10.",
      });
    }
  };

  const submitImages = async (publicationId) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    for (var x = 0; x < selectedFile.length; x++) {
      data.append("file", selectedFile[x]);
    }
    await postPublicationMultimedia(publicationId, data);

    return true

  };

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar></NavBar>
      <Container className="col-lg-12 m-2 p-2">
        <Form id="publicationForm">
          <Tabs activeKey={key} onSelect={(k) => setKey(k)}>
            <Tab
              eventKey="principal"
              title="Título"
              className="mt-3 p-2"
              disabled
            >
              <PrincipalTab
                nextTab={() => onChangeTab("details")}
                onChangeInput={() => onChangeInput}
                onChangeOptionCategory={() => onChangeOptionCategory}
                onChangeOptionMake={() => onChangeOptionMake}
                onChangeOptionModel={() => onChangeOptionModel}
                onChangeOptionVersion={() => onChangeOptionVersion}
                hasVehicleOtherSelected={() => hasVehicleOtherSelected}
                categories={categories}
                makes={makes}
                models={models}
                versions={versions}
                customMake={customMake}
                customModel={customModel}
                customVersion={customVersion}
                editResponse= {editResponse}
                //formData={formData}
              />
            </Tab>

            <Tab
              eventKey="details"
              title="Detalles"
              className="mt-3 p-2"
              disabled
            >
              <DetailsTab
                previousTab={() => onChangeTab("principal")}
                nextTab={() => onChangeTab("multimedia")}
                onChangeInput={() => onChangeInput}
              />
            </Tab>

            <Tab
              eventKey="multimedia"
              title="Imágenes"
              className="mt-3 p-2"
              disabled
            >
              <MultimediaTab
                previousTab={() => onChangeTab("details")}
                onChangeInput={() => onChangeInput}
                handleSubmit={() => handleSubmit}
                onChangeHandler={() => onChangeHandler}
                deleteFile={() => deleteFile}
                selectedFile={selectedFile}
              />
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </>
  );

}
```

La información con la que quiero trabajar la obtengo a través del hook "useEffect" que contiene la función "getPublicationEdit". La misma la paso al componente "PrincipalTab" en el cual debo tener un control dado que puede recibir la información de un elemento a editar o deberia estar vacia en el caso de cargar una publicacion nueva...

A continuacion dejo una porcion del elemento hijo donde recibo la prop e intento que se carguen los parametros en el caso que venga esa informacion

```
export default function PrincipalTab(props) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Form.Row>
        <Col>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Control
                  name="title"
                  placeholder="Titulo de la publicacion"
                  onChange={props.onChangeInput(this)}
                  required
                  value={props.editResponse ? props.editResponse.title : ""}
                 
              />
            <Form.Text>
              También puedes incluir: marca, modelo, año y version.
            </Form.Text>
          </Form.Group>
        </Col>
      </Form.Row>
      <br />
      <Form.Row>
        <Col>
          <Form.Label className="mx-2">Condición</Form.Label>
          <Form.Check
            inline
            custom
            label="Usado"
            name="condition"
            type="radio"
            value="Usado"
            required
            id="custom-inline-1"
            onChange={props.onChangeInput(this)}
          />
          <Form.Check
            inline
            custom
            label="Nuevo"
            name="condition"
            type="radio"
            value="Nuevo"
            required
            id="custom-inline-2"
            onChange={props.onChangeInput(this)}
          />
        </Col>
      </Form.Row>
      <br />
      <Form.Row>
        <Col sm="12" md="6">
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Control
              as="select"
              id="vehicleCategorySelect"
              onChange={props.onChangeOptionCategory(this)}
              name="vehicleCategoryId"
              required
            >
              <option selected disabled>
                Categoria
              </option>
              {props.categories.map((category) => (
                <option key={category.id} value={category.id}>
                  {category.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
        </Col>
```

Intente hacerlo de esta manera:

`value={props.editResponse ? props.editResponse.title : ""}`

No me carga el input con dicho valor, tampoco se como hacer en el caso de los combos...

Saludos!!

Comment: perdona por hacer esta pregunta tonta, pero ya hiciste console log de editCar.data.response antes de aplicar el setEditResponse, también logueaste props.editResponse antes del return en componente hijo? ambos coinciden bien?

Comment: hola! si.. esos ajustes ya los realice ! la info llega a los inputs ahora me falta resolver la parte de los combo que me esta dando trabajo!. 

En estos son los combos Category / Make... la idea es que al direccionar al formulario para editar una publicaciones me establezca el elemento con los valores de la publicación, además, también el mismo debe contener por ejemplo todas las marcas para poder modificar.

Comment: Este seria el bombo make a modo de ejemplo...
name="vehicleMakeId"

              `as="select"
              onChange={props.onChangeOptionMake(this)}
              required
            >
            {!props.formData.vehicleCategoryId ? (
              <option disabled>
                Marca
              </option> ) : ( <option selected disabled>
                Marca
              </option> )}
              {props.makes.map((make) => (
                <option key={make.id} value={make.id}>
                  {make.name}
                </option>
              ))})`

Comment: Nose si se entiende asi.. pero no pude hacerlo que copie la estructura con indentado y demás.. disculpas!

Comment: Solucione el inconveniente haciendo
`selected = {props.formData.vehicleCategoryId ? category.id === 
  props.formData.vehicleCategoryId : "Categoria" }>`
Ahora mi inconveniente es otro.... 
el primer combo "Categoria" recibe y setea esa informacion pero no sigue el proceso con los demas combos, es decir, para que haga lo mismo con "Marcas" esta esperando a que modifique algo en categorias sino no me setea al valor de la marca de la publicacion... nose como podria solucionar esta parte.

Comment: buenas tardes... solucionado! tuve que simular el onChange para que haga el proceso...

 `const event1 = new Event('change');
  const element = document.getElementById("vehicleCategorySelect"); 
  element.addEventListener("change", onChangeOptionCategory);
  element.dispatchEvent(event1); `